# How to limit what numbers a rand function could generate. (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to create a tic-tac-toe game in C++

So far, I have it set up where the player and the program take turns.
The program's move is determined by `rand()%10`.
It generates a number 1-9, one number for each box in tic tac toe.

But this becomes a problem because eventually it will select a box that has already been filled.
This seems to always cause a `Segmentation Fault`.

Is there any way to limit the `rand()` to boxes that are empty? I have tried if but they seem to be ignored. And then I would have to get `rand()` to keep trying until it generates a random number that corresponds to an empty box.

```
void program_move(){
    std::cout<<"My turn!\n";
    srand (time(NULL));
    move = rand()%10;
            if (boxes[move-1]!="x"&&boxes[move-1]!="o") {
    boxes[move-1]="o";
                
            }

    else{while(boxes[move-1]=="x"||boxes[move-1]=="o")
    {
        srand (time(NULL));
        move = rand()%10;
    
    boxes[move-1]="o";
        
    }
        
    }
```

Comment: ... and if you represent your 9 tic-tac-toe positions using array of `char boxes[9]`, with the upper-left corner being position `0`, down to the lower-right corner being position `8`, then you can just do `move = rand()%9;` and you won't have to subtract 1 from your `move` variable everywhere to get the correct behavior.  0-based indexing is the way to go in C++; 1-based indexing leads to off-by-one errors, as you have found.

Comment: Many thanks, everyone. I no longer get a `Segmentation Fault`. I even found a way to make the program find an empty tic-tac-toe box if `rand()` didn't. Though it's underwhelming that there is no "AI". I'm working on something now but I may end up making another question if I can't figure it out. We shall see...

Answer (score 3):

`rand()%10` generates `0-9`.
So `move` can be `0`.
In that case, accessing `boxes[move-1]` is out of bounds.

And you can try shuffling indexes instead of limiting the random generator.

i.e

```
std::vector<int> indices(10);
std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), gen);

for(auto i : indices)
  boxes[i] = "o";
```

p.s. If your `boxes`' size is 9, you have to change the `indices`' size to `9` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers to all contain the same number of digits, you either have to create a lot of random numbers. Or use some new functionality introduced in C++11, like the std::uniform_int_distribution class:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(100000000, 999999999);

for (int n = 1; n <= 5; ++n)
std::cout << "random number " << n << " = " << dis(gen) << '\n';
```

You can also just set the width of the output, and pad it with leading zeroes:

```
std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('0') << std::rand() << '\n';
```